# Nginx as reverse-proxy: serving files without extension

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, static-files

I'm currently using Nginx coupled with Apache, **serving following static files with success**.

Extract from my `/sites-enabled/default`:

```
location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|txt|xml)$ {
root /home/website/public_html/app/public;
}
```

---

But I also have some cache files located here:
`/home/website/public_html/app/storage/cache`
`/home/website/public_html/app/storage/views`
`/home/website/public_html/app/storage/sessions`

`/cache` and `/sessions` also have sub-directories. All sub-directories and files have random filename, and no extension.

**I want Nginx to also serve these files.**

I tried this (example for `/views` folder), but without success. I even have nothing in logs, but Nginx restart correctly, and website load with no errors.

```
location /views {
             alias /home/website/public/app/app/storage/views;
             access_log /var/log/nginx/web.views.access.log;
             error_log /var/log/nginx/web.views.error.log;
}
```

Tried this also, but same effects as above:

```
location ~* ^.$ {
             root /home/website/public/app/app/storage/views;
             access_log /var/log/nginx/web.views.access.log;
             error_log /var/log/nginx/web.views.error.log;
}
```

Also tried adding `add_header Content-Type application/octet-stream;` in these 2 tries, but no change.

Finally, here is the http part of my `nginx.conf`

```
http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log;

sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;
tcp_nodelay        on;

gzip  on;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";

include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

(`/var/log/nginx/access.log` and `/var/log/nginx/error.log` don't show up anything related to my issue, too).

Thanks for any clue and help !

EDIT

Complete current `/sites-enabled/default` file *(and yes, there's a double /app/, it's normal ;) )*

```
# You may add here your
# server {
#   ...
# } 
# statements for each of your virtual hosts

server {

listen   80; ## listen for ipv4
listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

server_name  www.website.com website.com;

#access_log  /var/log/nginx/localhost.access.log;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header Host $host;        
proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    access_log off;
    #root   /var/www;
    #index  index.html index.htm;
}

location ~* ^.+.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|txt|xml)$ {
  root /home/website/public_html/app/public;
  expires 30d;
}


location ~* ^.$ {
    add_header Content-Type application/octet-stream;
    root /home/website/public/app/app/storage/views;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/bt.views.access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/bt.views.error.log;
}

}
```

Comment: Please post your complete `sites-available/default` configuration file, I can help you than with a complete configuration and answer.

Comment: Sure, I just updated my post with it. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you need something to identify the files without any extension. A sub-directory or something that’s always present within the request. Your regular expression only matched for requests that start end end with a dot (e.g. `http://example.com/.`). The following server configuration assumes that all URLs start with `storage`, as this would be the only possibility to identify those files.

Please note that I’m using the `try_files` directive to rewrite the internal path where nginx should look for the file. The `root` directive is not meant for what you want to achieve.

And last but not least, you should always nest location blocks with regular expressions. There is no limit in the nesting level. nginx will create some kind of tree data structure to search for the best matching location. So think of a tree while writing the blocks.

```
server {
    listen        80 default;
    listen        [::]:80 default ipv6only=on;
    server_name   www.website.com website.com;
    root          /home/website/public_html/app;

    location / {

        # Matches any request for a URL ending on any of the extension
        # listed in the regular expression.
        location ~* \.(jpe?g|gif|css|png|js|ico|txt|xml)$ {
            expires     30d
            access_log  off;
            try_files   /public$uri =404;
        }

        # Matches any request starting with storage.
        location ~* ^/storage {
            access_log  /var/log/nginx/bt.views.access.log;
            error_log   /var/log/nginx/bt.views.error.log;
            try_files   /app$uri;
        }

        proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;        
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
        access_log        off;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Fleshgrinder. Clear explanation, and tips to help understand better how Nginx works. And nested like this, the file seems more logical to me ! Oh, and I just added the expected param in 2nd `try_files`, the "404 if fails" like you did in first one, and the missing `;` after the expiration param ;)